# RecyclerView SetOnClick onItemClick() doesn't get triggered / not functioning

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi In my app I have RecyclerView connect to the Cloud Firestore. When I try to add SetOnClick  to this recycler view it doesn't work. The app doesn't crash runs well but when I click on an item in the RecyclerView it doesn't do anything. The logcad doesn't change too so basically it doesnt function.

My adapter code:

```
    package com.example.ppw1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Listener;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;

import java.util.List;

public class ToDoAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ToDoItem, ToDoAdapter.ToDoHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public ToDoAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem> options) {
        super(options);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ToDoHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ToDoItem model) {

        holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDesc());

        String timeAgo = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeAdded().getSeconds()/1000);
       holder.dateAdded.setText(timeAgo);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ToDoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_to_do_item, parent,false);

        return new ToDoHolder(v);
    }

    public void deleteitem(int position)
    {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }



    class ToDoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title, description, dateAdded;


        public ToDoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoTitle);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoDesc);
            dateAdded = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateAdded);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });


        }


    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

My set on click listener
Note: The on swape and on move works in this function

```
  private void setUpRecyclerView()
{
    Query query = todoRef.whereEqualTo("email", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ToDoItem>().setQuery(query,ToDoItem.class).build();


   adapter = new ToDoAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.firestore_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

  new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
          ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
      @Override
      public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
          adapter.deleteitem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

      }
  }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

  adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ToDoAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
         ToDoItem note = documentSnapshot.toObject(ToDoItem.class);
          String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
          String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
          Toast.makeText(ListActivities.this,
                  "Position: " + position + " ID: " + "Path" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  });
```

My activity to do layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFE">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Line"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todoDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Second Line"
            android:layout_below="@id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateAdded"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Thirtd Line"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/todoDesc" />



    </RelativeLayout>




</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: which part is not working .. is `onItemClick()` get triggered?

Comment: No, it is not get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it in `onBindViewHolder` instead of the `ViewHolder` constructor

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    
    // ...
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (listener != null) {
               listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
            }
        }
    });
    
}
```

And remove it from the `ViewHolder`

```
class ToDoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title, description, dateAdded;


    public ToDoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoTitle);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoDesc);
        dateAdded = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateAdded);
    }

}
```

Applying that to the adapter:

```
public class ToDoAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ToDoItem, ToDoAdapter.ToDoHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public ToDoAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ToDoHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull ToDoItem model) {

        holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDesc());

        String timeAgo = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeAdded().getSeconds()/1000);
        holder.dateAdded.setText(timeAgo);

        
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ToDoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_to_do_item, parent,false);

        return new ToDoHolder(v);
    }

    public void deleteitem(int position)
    {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }



    class ToDoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title, description, dateAdded;


        public ToDoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoTitle);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoDesc);
            dateAdded = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateAdded);

        }


    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

add `android:clickable="true"` & `android:focusable="true"` to the root element of the row item layout..

So update `activity_to_do_item` layout with:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFE">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Line"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todoDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Second Line"
            android:layout_below="@id/todoTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateAdded"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Thirtd Line"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/todoDesc" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new at android studio. I couldn't manage the make the chances can you send the updated code please ?

Comment: listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);

comes up with an error saying : Variable 'position' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: @AbdullahErgun I updated the answer .. just mark `position` with `final`

Comment: I have also uploaded the activity_to_do_item if that helps. I now updating the code to see if it works.

Comment: Error is gone but still doesn't work @Zain

Comment: When you run the app, the `RecyclerView` contains data from firestore ?

Comment: Yes it does I can also delete items by sliding but SetOnClick doesn't work

Comment: please check updated answer .. now the change in the layout

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on this line of code `listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);` and then debug the code instead of running it

Comment: @AbdullahErgun I will try to think again .. please leave me a tag when you find the answer